# In DS9: Paradise Lost, why is a vice admiral in charge of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, starfleet-rank, starfleet-command

In the Deep Space 9 episode, *Paradise Lost* ([S04E12](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paradise_Lost_(episode))):

> Vice Admiral Leyton tries to take over the federation by creating a fake Dominion threat and getting the Federation president to declare emergency powers.  These emergency powers, which should fall on the head of Starfleet, appear to fall on Leyton.

Why is Leyton considered the "head of Starfleet"?  He is wearing a 3-pip admiral insignia, which is vice admiral, a solid two ranks below Fleet Admiral.

Comment: Everyone has their vices...

Comment: He was [Head of Starfleet Operations on Earth](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Leyton), basically a key position for any would-be dictator with their own following.

Comment: Yeah - he's the local head of Starfleet

Comment: Is "bad writing" or "plot hole" sufficient as an answer? How 'bout, "Because JK Rowling is bad at maths"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### I think your premise is wrong; Leyton's not in charge of Starfleet - he's in charge of the local Starfleet forces.

###### And in the case of an emergency on Earth, response belongs with the commanders of local Starfleet forces - i.e. with Leyton and his allies. A higher-ranking officer with bigger jobs would be immediately out of place if he did what Leyton did.

Starfleet is a huge organization, operating over a large portion of the galaxy; its top leadership therefore has very high rank. But the military works by [chain of command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_hierarchy):

> Orders are transmitted down the chain of command, from a responsible
> superior, such as a commissioned officer, to lower-ranked
> subordinate(s) who either execute the order personally or transmit it
> down the chain as appropriate, until it is received by those expected
> to execute it. "Command is exercised by virtue of office and the
> special assignment of members of the Armed Forces holding military
> rank who are eligible to exercise command."
>
> In general, military personnel give orders only to those directly
> below them in the chain of command and receive orders only from those
> directly above them.

Leyton's cover story is that there is a local threat to Earth (infiltration by Changelings); therefore he is the appropriate person to handle local security issues, by virtue of his apparent authority over local forces (as Head of Starfleet Operations - note that he personally assigned Sisko as acting head of Starfleet Security).

It would be an immediate red flag if the head of Starfleet itself (a person who is in charge of all of Starfleet's far-flung forces) took personal control over security of even such an important place as Earth, while having a local commander institute "temporary" measures is much less suspicious.

Imagine if (to take a wild example), there was an attack on the Parliament in London; the head of palace security might do a lot of things to protect the building and the legislature without question, but if the head of the UK military took personal control of the situation, he would be seen as:

1. Abandoning his other tasks (what if the attack on the Parliament is a diversion to distract from a strategic assault on shipyards, airfields and the like?).
2. Confusing lines of control, and…
3. Raising the possibility of a military coup.

Comment: This is largely a good answer, but I think the chain of command piece confuses the issue.  Nowhere in the episode do we see Leyton being given this authority by a higher admiral.

Comment: Trimmed a bit, and added some details to clarify (I hope)